# querying a spatial database

Tags: oracle11g, netbeans-7

I am using ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER .
I have created the table

```
Create table building(
building_ID varchar2(5) Primary Key, 
building_name Varchar2(50),
shape MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA 
  VALUES (
  'building',
  'shape',
  SDO_DIM_ARRAY(   -- 20X20 grid
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', 0, 100, 1),
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 0, 100, 1)
     ),
  NULL   -- SRID
);

CREATE INDEX building_index
   ON building(shape)
   INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

and inserted the values using java program using executeUpdate()

now I query oracle database using

```
select * from building;
```

and all rows appears, output is-
[image]

but when I query the oracle database

```
SELECT building_ID
  FROM building 
  WHERE building_name = 'SSL'; OR

  SELECT c.shape.GET_GTYPE()
  FROM building c WHERE c.building_name = 'BHE';
```

or likewise statements with where clause no row appears. What is the problem please help

Comment: What do you get if you `SELECT building_name, dump(building_name) FROM building`?  Is it possible that the actual building names have additional spaces at the end, for example?

Comment: snippet of the output of your query-                                                                  PSA Typ=1 Len=4: 32,80,83,65
OHE Typ=1 Len=4: 32,79,72,69
BHE Typ=1 Len=4: 32,66,72,69                                     and yes I have one white space before the building name. and adding the white space giving me the desired output .. Thank you.. but Is there a way to eliminate this white space problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your Java application appears to have inserted the data with a leading space.  In the `DUMP` output, you'll see that the length of each data element is 4 and the first byte is 32 which maps to a space in the [ASCII charcter set](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You should be able to query the data by prepending a space

```
SELECT *
  FROM building
 WHERE building_name = ' SSL'
```

or you can modify your data to remove the leading space and use your existing queries.

```
UPDATE building
   SET building_name = TRIM(building_name);
```

Assuming you do this, you'll also need to modify your Java application so that it isn't inserting the leading space in the future.